# App Freezing when getting data from the internet

Tags: android, httpclient, freeze

I'm having a problem that i'm sure that it's really simple to solve but i'm still starting on app developing so i thought you could help me out.
I got an app that has a currency converter in it, and when i push the button to get the conversion it freezes while it's getting the data from the internet and then comes back to life after some seconds. Here is the code:

```
   public void capturaConversao(String m1, String m2) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        BufferedReader resp = null;
        endereco = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + m1
                + m2 + "=X&f=sl1d1t1ba&e=.csv";
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet method = new HttpGet(endereco);
            HttpResponse statusCode = client.execute(method);
            resp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(statusCode
                    .getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            while ((line = resp.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            resp.close();
            String result = sb.toString();
            String[] values = result.split(",");
            conversion = values[1];
            nextstep++;

        } finally {
            if (resp != null) {
                try {
                    resp.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Não foi possível se conectar à internet.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is the solution for almost all the UI thread woes. :)
Here's a short [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).

Comment: Thanks Man! This is really easy to set up and learn! Worked perfect for my app! I really need to learn about thread working but for now the AsyncTask made the work!

Answer (score 0):

You are likely calling this from the UI thread, which you should not do.  It makes the UI lock up, because the UI thread is busy connecting to the internet.  [Here's a tutorial for making such a call](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=290).

Comment: Thaanks for the tutorial man! I voted for the other cause right now the AsyncTask made the work well... But for sure i'll have to learn about thread working and this tutorial is a very good start!

Answer (score 0):

Your UI thread's available cycles are being hogged by the HTTP actions.  Seperate it out with either a `Thread` or an `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 0):

Yes i am also agree to go with AsyncTask solution and as it is known as Painless Threading, user need to not to bother about Thread Management.

For your case, just **call the capturaConversao() method inside doInBackground()** (i.e. do all data fetching operation from web inside the doInBackground method) and **call the display method inside the onPostExecute()** (i.e. do all display operation like display fetched values inside the listview or textview).